# PHPのeAcceleratorでsegmentation faultがでる状況や原因について

Tags: php, apache

## 環境

- apache 2.2.15 (prefork)
- php 5.3.3
- eAccelerator 1.0-dev
- アプリは自前のPHPアプリ

## お聞きしたいこと

eAcceleratorでSegmentation Faultが出るという事例がいくつか
（http://www.multiburst.net/sometime-php/2010/06/eaccelerator/　や
http://u-tamax.jp/2012/04/httpd-%E3%81%A7-segmentation-fault-11-%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F/　や
http://bucci.bp7.org/archives/414）があるようです。

似た現象に遭遇しておりまして、これを再現するための状況や原因について推測されることはどんなことがありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決方法のアドバイスとしては次の通りです。

- バイナリパッケージをすべてアップデートする
- ソースからビルドしたものはその後で再度ビルドしてインストールする
- 最適化オプション等を指定しているのなら外す
- 公式リポジトリ以外のバイナリパッケージは使わない(特に何かが依存してそうなもの)
- バイナリパッケージが依存しているライブラリをソースからインストールしない

原因や再現方法となると情報不足ですので一般論でしか言えませんが、

- バイナリパッケージ間での依存関係不整合(バージョン不整合)
- apacheかphpかeAcceleratorか依存ライブラリか開発環境のバグ
- ファイル破損
- OSのバグ
- ハードウェア故障

あたりです。

Comment: 参考になりました、ありがとうございます。
解決方法としてはごもっともですが、根本原因について調査する必要があり、その目処をつけたかったところです。